# React Native javascript changes not reflecting in ios simulator

Tags: xcode, react-native, ios-simulator, watchman

I'm building a React Native application, and the javascript code updates are not reflecting in the ios Simulator. I have restarted the development server with `react-native start` and `react-native start --reset-cache`. I have used `react-native-clean-project` to clean the pods folder, node_modules, and various other caches. I tried reinstalling `watchman`. All these efforts have not worked.

The issue started about a week ago, until that time the javascript code was updating normally. And it currently will update when a file is changed with the hot reloads, but then when I rerun `react-native run-ios` it goes back to version of the javascript that was there previously.

Building the app directly from XCode doesn't work either. It still builds with the outdated javascript. Does anyone have any ideas on what may be causing this issue?

Comment: same problem here :( I temporary solved this by turning off JS debugging